# How to manage a buffer containing objects of varying size? For sparse chunk loading/unloading

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am making an open world game in c++ where chunks dynamically load around the player. Each chunk is a SVO (sparse voxel octree), and due to their sparse nature, each chunk is a different size. This means i can't just use something like a pool allocator.

The chunk buffer needs to be a contiguous block of memory, since it's synced to the GPU every frame. This also means that sorting the buffer on the CPU and sending it to the GPU every frame is not feasible.

To summarize, I am looking for a memory manager that:

- handles objects of different sizes
- limits the shifting of memory to a reasonable degree

Because the problem is a bit specific, I am struggling to find resources on what memory manager would be best!

also, someone suggested me this manager:
https://github.com/schulkinator/memorymanager
and I would appreciate others' opinions on it.

Comment: Isn't that precisely what new/delete are doing ?

Comment: Seeking recommendation is kind of out of scope for questions here. You know your datastructure then anyone out here. It is not only about buffering but also about the structure of the tree itself (data coherency). Any pool (of memory) will in the end suffer from fragmentation. But looks like something with in-place new might be an option.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean "You know your datastructure then anyone out here." I dont have a specified data structure; im trying to maintain a contiguous block of memory with different sized objects (it doesn't matter that they're SVOs).

Comment: Yves, the difference is that i need all the memory to be in a contiguous block because i send it to the gpu.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem: you are convinced you need a single contiguous buffer (problem X) because you are doing a full copy (every frame, even) (problem Y). All graphics APIs support *partial updates* to buffers, so you are solving the wrong problem. It is also very wasteful to send the full buffer on every frame instead of only the parts that changed. Can you edit your question with the way you synchronize your buffer? Then we can suggest an alternative that does partial updates/

Comment: Botje - when i said "This also means that sorting the buffer on the CPU and sending it to the GPU every frame is not feasible" that's because I sync via partial updates, and I am trying to avoid updating the entire buffer...

Comment: so if you already sync via partial updates, what stops you from syncing from multiple source buffers instead of a single contiguous one? In the end, your graphics card DMA engine only needs to know "this CPU-side address goes to this GPU-side address". Alternatively, you can `mmap` a terabyte-sized memory hole at the start and then only pay memory for what you actually use.

Comment: Oh you're right i could do that! The reason I was constraining myself to one buffer was because I'm going to be loading and unloading thousands of chunks. Is that reasonable to use a new buffer for each chunk, or at least a buffer per a group of chunks?